# toad plsql error executing stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, toad

For no obvious reason I got this error:

> *ORA-00942: table or view does not exist*

with debug cursor being set in line:

```
 SELECT AMD.MSG_DATE
```

from the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CTI_MATRIX.AMD_NEEDMSG (v_CRN IN VARCHAR2)
IS

return_flag INTEGER;
row_cnt INTEGER;
number_of_days INTEGER;
var_DATE DATE;

CURSOR ACCNTSEARCH (P_CRN IN VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT AMD.MSG_DATE    
       FROM TBL_AMD_NEEDMSG AMD
      WHERE AMD.PHONE_NUMBER = P_CRN;

BEGIN

OPEN ACCNTSEARCH(v_CRN);
FETCH ACCNTSEARCH INTO var_DATE;
IF ACCNTSEARCH%NOTFOUND 
THEN
    row_cnt := 0;
ELSE
    row_cnt :=1;
END IF;
CLOSE ACCNTSEARCH;

IF (row_cnt = 0)
THEN
        INSERT INTO TBL_AMD_NEEDMSG (PHONE_NUMBER, MSG_DATE) VALUES (v_CRN , SYSDATE); 
        return_flag := 1;
ELSE
    SELECT SYSDATE-var_DATE INTO number_of_days FROM dual;

     IF (number_of_days>7)
    THEN 
        UPDATE TBL_AMD_NEEDMSG SET MSG_DATE = SYSDATE WHERE PHONE_NUMBER = v_CRN;
        return_flag := 1;
    ELSE
         return_flag := 0;
    END IF;

END IF;    

COMMIT;

dbms_output.put_line('result='||return_flag );    
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    --raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered '||SQLERRM);


END AMD_NEEDMSG;
/
```

By the way, the stored procedure is called via following calling block:

```
DECLARE 
 V_CRN VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN 
 V_CRN := '5457648547567';
 CTI_MATRIX.AMD_NEEDMSG ( V_CRN );
 DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('');

 COMMIT; 
END;
```

Absolutely puzzled since table definitely exists and following statement:

```
SELECT AMD.MSG_DATE    
       FROM TBL_AMD_NEEDMSG AMD
      WHERE AMD.PHONE_NUMBER =  '85100000000';
```

Fetches recordset result w/o problem.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe the error is not due to the specific line you are on, but some query TOAD is trying to execute?  Try running TOAD's SQL Monitor or SQL Tracker and monitor toad.exe.  It will trap all the SQL calls toad is making, and maybe you can see what is the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are your scheme are the same with CTI_MATRIX?
I mean are you run your select under CTI_MATRIX user, because as I see you create stored procedure in this scheme. 
good luck

Comment: Yeah that was Toad problem, running in debug mode. Lines of code that this happens is within cursor declaration. After several OK clicks massage goes away and execution resumes as expected, stepping over line by line. Thanks anyway. But interesting and very misleading behaviour.